# How to separate vue.js template into a .vue file while leaving code in .js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-loader

I want to separate the vue.js template into a .vue file while leaving code in a .js file.

This is a vue "single file component":

```
<template>
..
</template>

<script>
..
</script>
```

**What works**:

Make the .vue file the real component, and define a MIXIN that points to the .js file. *Seems very hacky!*

**What I would like:**

A single webpack import to the .js file:

```
...
</template>

import ViewModel from 'vm.js'
```

Is this possible? Or a  tag in the .vue file that vue-loader understands?

```
<template>
..
<script src='vm.js'/>
</template>
```

---

Thanks a ton! The goal is to set breakpoints in visual studio code + separation of concerns + readability. :)

**Oh, and this needs to work with typescript!**

Comment: As someone who is still learning vue, from what I understand is that vue needs the template/js in one file in order for it to be compiled into a component for web usage. However, if this is in fact possible I would like to know as well...

Comment: Can't you just wrap the import in script tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
...
</template>

import ViewModel from 'vm.js'
```

The second option is possible with a small tweak made in it

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script src="vm.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll try it out and accept the answer if it works. :)

Comment: What about typescript... I'm working right now on moving our vue.js codebase to it. Do I just include a "vm.ts"? I'm not sure webpack and vue-loader is that smart...

Comment: Support for typescript is available. I haven't tried it yet for my projects though. You can check out https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: Looks like we might need to add:
<script lang="ts">. Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter